# How do I change the background color of the eclipse expression value window?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse, Helios 2, Ubuntu 11, in VirtualBox on Windows.

In Java debug mode, hovering over a variable displays it's value.

However, I am getting gray text on a black background.  How can I change the background color for the expression value window?

I did not find a way to do this via Windows/Preferences/General/Appearance/Colors and Fonts, or anywhere else for that matter.

Comment: Same problem here.  I'm running Eclipse-CDT Kepler on Ubuntu 11 with Dark Juno plugin, so expressions look like dark grey text on black editor background.  Quite hard to see...